# How to replace multiple matches in Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace '=' with '==' in the following string:

```
log="[x] = '1' and [y] <> '7' or [z]='51'".
```

Unfortunately, only the second '=' is getting replaced. Why is the first one not being replaced and how do I replace the first one as well?

```
def subs_equal_sign(logic):
    y = re.compile(r'\]\s?\=\s?')
    iterator = y.finditer(logic)
    for match in iterator:
        j = str(match.group())
    return logic.replace(j, ']==')
```

The output should be:

```
log="[x] == '1' and [y] <> '7' or [z]=='51'".
```

This is what i get instead:

```
log="[x] = '1' and [y] <> '7' or [z]=='51'".
```

Comment: Why not `return logic.replace('=', '==')`? Or `re.sub(r'(]\s*)=', r'\1==', logic)`?

Comment: The output has to be  `log="[x] == '1' and [y] <> '7' or [z]=='51'".`  or  `"[x] == '1' and [y] <> '7' or [z]=='51'".` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for match in iterator:
        j = str(match.group())
    return logic.replace(j, ']==')
```

This part goes through the matches and doesn't do any replacing.

Only when you leave the loop, you do replacing - that's why it changes only the last one. ;)

---

Also, you do replacing without using the regex - simple `str.replace` takes all substrings matches and replaces them. So if your first `=` didn't have space before, it would get changed anyway!

Looking at your regex, there is only one space possible between `]` and `=`, so why not do the replacing on those two cases, instead of using regexes? ;)

```
def subs_equal_sign(logic):
    return logic.replace(']=', ']==').replace('] =', ']==')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the replace() function is what you are looking for :

```
log="[x] = '1' and [y] <> '7' or [z]='51'"
log = log.replace("=", "==")
```

Comment: OP said the whole line `log="[x] = '1' and [y] <> '7' or [z]='51'".` is a string, not a variable `log` containing a string, and that `=` -> `==` doesn't work because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to

```
def subs_equal_sign(logic):
    y = re.compile(r'\]\s?\=\s?')
    return y.sub("]==", logic)
```

and the output will now be

```
>>> subs_equal_sign('''log="[x] = '1' and [y] <> '7' or [z]='51'".''')
'log="[x]==\'1\' and [y] <> \'7\' or [z]==\'51\'".'
```

as expected.

@h4z3 correctly pointed out that your key problem is iterating through the matched groups without doing anything to them. You can make it work by simply using [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace all occurrences at once.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to deal with this is to remove the whitespace:

```py
def subs_equal_sign(logic):
    for k in range(len(logic))):
        logic[k].replace(' ','')
    y = re.compile(r'\]\s?\=\s?')
    iterator = y.finditer(logic)
    for match in iterator:
        j = str(match.group())
    return logic.replace(j, ']==')
```

Does the string represent the branching logic for a REDCap variable?  If so, I wrote a function a while back that should convert REDCap's SQL-like syntax to a pythonic form.  Here it is:

```py
def make_pythonic(str):

    """
        Takes the branching logic string of a field name
        and converts the syntax to that of Python.
    """

    # make list of all checkbox vars in branching_logic string
    #    NOTE: items in list have the same serialization (ordering) 
    #    as in the string.
    checkbox_snoop = re.findall('[a-z0-9_]*\([0-9]*\)', str)

    # if there are entries in checkbox_snoop
    if len(checkbox_snoop) > 0:

        # serially replace "[mycheckboxvar(888)]" syntax of each
        # checkbox var in the logic string with the appropraite
        # "record['mycheckboxvar___888']" syntax
        for item in checkbox_snoop:

            item = re.sub('\)', '', item)
            item = re.sub('\(', '___', item)

            str = re.sub('[a-z0-9_]*\([0-9]*\)', item, str)


    # mask and substitute
    str = re.sub('<=', 'Z11Z', str)
    str = re.sub('>=', 'X11X', str)
    str = re.sub('=', '==', str)
    str = re.sub('Z11Z', '<=', str)
    str = re.sub('X11X', '>=', str)
    str = re.sub('<>', '!=', str)
    str = re.sub('\[', 'record[\'', str)
    str = re.sub('\]', '\']', str)

    # return the string
    return str
```

Answer (score 0):

**This could replace the given character with the new char to be replaced in the entire string.**
    log=log.replace("=","==")#Replaces the given substring with new string
    print(log)#Display